# Android Data Binding Error : Compilation Error while importing the class with same name as java.lang.Error in layout file

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, android-architecture-components

In my code, I have created a sealed Resource class with Success, Error & Loading status like below:

```
package com.sample.githubsample.vo

sealed class Resource<T>(val data: T?, val message: String? = null)

class Success<T>(data: T?) : Resource<T>(data)

class Error<T>(data: T?, message: String?) : Resource<T>(data, message)

class Loading<T>(data: T?) : Resource<T>(data)
```

I am trying to use Resource class in my xml layout to manipulate view's visibility. Following is my layout file (trending_fragment.xml) :

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <import type="android.view.View" />
        <import type="com.sample.githubsample.vo.Success" />
        <import type="com.sample.githubsample.vo.Loading" />
        <import type="com.sample.githubsample.vo.Error" />

    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/pull_to_refresh"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/repo_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

However I am getting following error:

```
e: [kapt] An exception occurred: android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data   `  `binding error(s):`
[databinding] {"msg":"Error has already been defined as java.lang.Error but trying to re-define as 
com.sample.githubsample.vo.Error","file":"D:\\KotlinProjects\\GithubSample\\app\\src\\main
\\res\\layout\\trending_fragment.xml","pos":[]}

at android.databinding.tool.processing.Scope.assertNoError(Scope.java:111)
at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding.doProcess(ProcessDataBinding.java:124)
at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding.process(ProcessDataBinding.java:88)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.incremental.IncrementalProcessor.process(incrementalProcessors.kt)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.ProcessorWrapper.process(annotationProcessing.kt:147)
```

If I rename my Error class to some other name which doesn't conflict with Java default classes, then it is working correctly.

I tried with type alias in data binding but still got the same error.
Is there any limitation in using class names in layouts while using data binding?

Comment: What happens if you declare the subclasses as members of the superclass (i.e., within the superclass body)? Then you'd be able to refer to them as `Resource.Error` instead of simply `Error`.

Comment: I tried with that still getting the same error.

Comment: After making that change, what do your `<import>` tags look like? If you're still writing something like `<import type="com.sample.githubsample.vo.Resource.Error" />` I'd expect it to fail, but could you instead write `<import type="com.sample.githubsample.vo.Resource" />`?

Comment: Yes that is working. Actually I have a variable of type Resource in my layout. I need to check if that variable is instanceeof Success, Error or Loading to manipulate some view's visibility. As of now I have renamed the Error class to Error1 and it is working fine.